# Backup de cpanel no puedo abrirlo en local xampp

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Estoy haciendo modificaciones a una pagina que esta en produccion, quise descargar un backup para editarla en desarrollo y la he tratado de subir en xampp pero me da muchos errores con la base de datos. Ya he creado la base de dato y he restaurado la que he bajado del cpanel pero aun es imposible abrirla.

Comment: Esta pregunta necesita mejorarse: ¿Cómo es imposible abrirla? ¿Recibes algún error? ¿Aparece algo en los logs o algún mensaje en la pantalla? Tal y como está planteada, lo más que vamos a poder hacer son conjeturas de por qué falla y no vamos a poder ayudarte del todo. Lee [ask] en el centro de ayuda para obtener más información y completa el [tour] (ganando así tu primera medalla).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

posiblemente las versiones de base de datos sean incompatibles es muy común hacer un backup de una base de datos moderna a una más antigua o viceversa y entonces los errores aparecen por montones.

para evitar esos errores lo mejor es usar algún cliente de base de datos que no sea el clásico phpmyadmin. y en vez de generar el archivo sql descargarlo y volverlo a cargar. mejor es hacer una transferencia de datos.

[transferencia de base a base](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUpaFJF0WE4)